# Sinatra HAML Heroku in-file templates

Tags: heroku, sinatra, haml

I'm following a tutorial from http://ruby.about.com/od/sinatra/a/sinatra7_2.htm however I'm having a few problems running the app within my own environment.

The problem is that the following line:

```
   haml :list, :locals => { :cs => Contact.all }
```

results in a "No such file or directory - [...]/views/list.haml"

The HAML template is within the file, and terminated by:

```
 __END__
 @@ layout
```

however ruby seems to be looking in the views/ directory for the Haml files.

Is this tutorial missing a call to force ruby to look inside the file, or [this resource](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/36235491/using-erb-inline-templates-w-sinatra-on-192p0-broken.aspx) suggests that in-file templates are broken for version 1.9.2.

I'm using sinatra version 1.1.2 and ruby 1.8.7.

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce with Sinatra 1.1.2 and Ruby 1.9.2.

So something like this (sinatrarb.com) example generates the error?

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  haml :index
end

__END__

@@ layout
%html
  = yield

@@ index
%div.title Hello world!!!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

calling a list template you will also need add it to the end of your file:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  haml :list
end

__END__

@@ layout
%html
  = yield

@@ list
%div.title the LIST
```